# Close mini-cart dropdown automatically after 2 seconds in WooCommerce

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

In my woocommerce shop, [link](https://pharmers.co.il), I have changed the add to cart button, when a user click on the add to cart button the cart dropdown is droping from to top, how can i close it after 2 seconds unless touched, (flatsome theme)
someone can help me figure out what js or other solution i can add to make the cart dropdown close itself after 2 secods?

If someone wants to add a quantity box with +/- next to the add to cart that will show the cart dropdown here is the codes: enjoy.

```
    <script>
// JS
function addToCartLink(evt, pid) {
    var x = jQuery("#quantity_" + pid);
    var y = evt.closest("div");
    var qty = y.getElementsByClassName("input-text")[0].value;

 const addToCartUrl = '/?wc-ajax=add_to_cart';
    var xWWWFormUrlencodedData = "quantity=" + qty;
xWWWFormUrlencodedData += "&product_id=" + pid;
 jQuery.post(addToCartUrl, xWWWFormUrlencodedData, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            'Pragma': 'no-cache'
        }
    }).success(result => {
        if (result.error) {
            console.warn('The product has been added to the cart despite that the result object indicates an error!');
            return;
        }
        console.log('Success.', result);
        jQuery("div.widget_shopping_cart_content").replaceWith(result.fragments["div.widget_shopping_cart_content"]);
        jQuery("span.mega-menu-woo-cart-total").replaceWith(result.fragments["span.mega-menu-woo-cart-total"]);
        jQuery("span.mega-menu-woo-cart-count").replaceWith(result.fragments["span.mega-menu-woo-cart-count"]);
        jQuery(".header .cart-icon").replaceWith(result.fragments[".header .cart-icon"]);
        jQuery(".image-icon.header-cart-icon").replaceWith(result.fragments[".image-icon.header-cart-icon"]);
jQuery(".cart-price").replaceWith(result.fragments[".cart-price"]);
        jQuery("li.cart-item.has-icon.has-dropdown").addClass("current-dropdown");



    });

 return false;

}
</script>
```

and in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() && ! is_cart() ) {

        $html = '<a rel="nofollow" data-product_id="'. $product->id .'" onclick="addToCartLink(this,' . $product->id .')" class="add_to_cart_button product_type_simple button primary is-flat mb-0 is-small">הוסף לסל</a>';
        //$html = '<a onclick="addToCartLink(this,'. $product->id .')">הוסף לסל</a>';

        $html .= '<div class="quantity buttons_added">';
        $html .= '<input type="button"  value="-"  class="minus button is-form">';
        $html .= '<input type="number" id="quantity_'. $product->id .'" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="0" max="9999" name="quantity" value="1" title="כמות" size="4" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" >';
        $html .= '<input type="button" value="+" class="plus button is-form">';
        $html .= '</div>';

    }
    return $html;
}
```

Comment: You should need to give us a live website link (editing your question please)…

Comment: Here is the link [link](https://pharmers.co.il), add a product to the cart, 
The Cart will drop from the top,
How can I add a js to close it after 2 seconds ?
Thanks Loic:)

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this *(without guaranty as I can't test it)*:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_jquery_script' );
function custom_jquery_script(){
    ?>
    <script>
        (function($){
            $('body').on( 'added_to_cart', function(){
                setTimeout( function(){
                    $('ul.nav.top-bar-nav > .cart-item').removeClass('current-dropdown');
                }, 2000 );
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

---

**Explanations:**

When an item is added to cart, class `current-dropdown` is added to:

```
<li class="cart-item has-icon has-dropdown">
```

and will apply a CSS to this Child html element to make it visible *(the cart popin content)*:

```
<ul class="nav-dropdown nav-dropdown-default" style="">
```

So with my jQuery code, I catch "body" delegated event `added_to_cart` and I use setTimeout() javascript function to remove that `current-dropdown` class after 2 seconds `(2000 milli seconds)`. When removing the class, it hides automatically the mini-cart content pop-in…

That should be the right way.

---

**If it doesn't work**, you can try *(2 alternatives)*:

1) to replace in the code `'added_to_cart'` by `'adding_to_cart'` event instead 
2) to replace `$('body').on( 'added_to_cart', function(){` by:

```
$('.add_to_cart_button').click( function(){
```

I hope it will work…

Comment: Thanks again for your help. unfortunately it didn't work, I tried all scenarios, any clue why ? thanks

Comment: @itayko **So know may be the problem is:** How do you embed this script? Even if it doesn't work at all for now (remember that I can't test it for real), Is this answer do not deserve to be upvoted as my explanations are the real process...

Comment: i'm embeding this code inside the header, i tried also in the footer, is it working for you in inspect mode ? 
the cart need to be closed automatically without touching with the mouse, is this possible ? :(

Comment: I upvoted u, you are great, unfortunately, it's still not working :(